# Search form redirect to results page

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, forms, search

We have set up a search form on the homepage of our website to display property results on a different page. A site visitor can select price, city, etc. on the homepage and is then redirected to view the results on a different page. When they select a property on the results page, there is the option to go back to the search results.

When a site visitor searches from the homepage, views one of the results, and then goes back to the search results, it displays all listings in the database instead of the search results.

We have search forms on the results page, as well. When a visitor searches from the search forms on that page, views a listing, clicks to go back to search results, it displays the correct search results.

Here is the code we are using:

search form homepage:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/wp/residential-listings/">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<h1 style="color:#ffffff; text-align:center;">FIND YOUR NEW HOME</h1>


<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<!-- Select Basic -->

  <div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align:center;"><label for="city">City:</label>
<select id="city" name="city" class="form-control">
<option value="all-cities" disabled">Select:</option>
<option value="all-cities" disabled>DeKalb County</option>
<option value="COLLINSVILLE">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Collinsville</option>
<option value="CROSSVILLE">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Crossville</option>
<option value="DAWSON">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dawson</option>
<option value="FLAT ROCK">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Flat Rock</option>
<option value="FORT PAYNE">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fort Payne</option>
<option value="FYFFE">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fyffe</option>
<option value="GERALDINE">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Geraldine</option>
<option value="HAMMONDVILLE">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hammondville</option>
<option value="HENAGAR">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Henagar</option>
<option value="IDER">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ider</option>
<option value="MENTONE">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mentone</option>
<option value="PISGAH">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Pisgah</option>
<option value="POWELL">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Powell</option>
<option value="RAINSVILLE">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Rainsville</option>
<option value="SECTION">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Section</option>
<option value="VALLEY HEAD">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Valley Head</option>
<option value="all-cities" disabled>Cherokee County</option>
<option value="CEDAR BLUFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cedar Bluff</option>
<option value="CEDARTOWN">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cedartown</option>
<option value="CENTRE">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Centre</option>
<option value="CHEROKEE">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cherokee</option>
<option value="LEESBURG">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Leesburg</option>
<option value="PAINT ROCK">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Paint Rock</option>
<option value="SAND ROCK">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sand Rock</option>
<option value="SECTION">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Section</option>
<option value="all-cities" disabled>Jackson County</option>
<option value="BRIDGEPORT">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bridgeport</option>
<option value="DUTTON">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dutton</option>
<option value="GURLEY">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Gurley</option>
<option value="HOKES BLUFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hokes Bluff</option>
<option value="HOLLYWOOD">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hollywood</option>
<option value="HYTOP">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hytop</option>
<option value="SCOTTSBORO">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Scottsboro</option>
<option value="STEVENSON">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stevenson</option>
    </select></div>

<!-- Select Basic -->

 <div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align:center;"><label for="price-min">Min. Price:</label>
<select id="price-min" name="price-min" class="form-control">
      <option value="0">No Minimum</option>
<option value="50000">50,000</option>
<option value="100000">100,000</option>
<option value="150000">150,000</option>
<option value="200000">200,000</option>
<option value="250000">250,000</option>
<option value="300000">300,000</option>
<option value="350000">350,000</option>
<option value="400000">400,000</option>
<option value="450000">450,000</option>
<option value="500000">500,000</option>
    </select></div>


<!-- Select Basic -->

  <div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align:center;"><label for="price-max">Max. Price:</label>
<select id="price-max" name="price-max" class="form-control">
      <option value="999999999">No Maximum</option>
<option value="100000">100,000</option>
<option value="150000">150,000</option>
<option value="200000">200,000</option>
<option value="250000">250,000</option>
<option value="300000">300,000</option>
<option value="350000">350,000</option>
<option value="400000">400,000</option>
<option value="450000">450,000</option>
<option value="500000">500,000</option>
<option value="999999999">No Maximum</option>
    </select></div>


<!-- Select Basic -->

  <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center;"><label for="beds">Min. Beds:</label>
<select id="beds" name="beds" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select></div>


<!-- Select Basic -->

  <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:center;"><label for="baths">Min. Baths:</label>
<select id="baths" name="baths" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center;">
    <button class="fusion-button button-flat button-round button-large button-default button-1" type="submit" value="SEARCH" style="text-align:center;">SEARCH</button>
  </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

search form on results page:

```
<form method="post" action="/wp/residential-listings/">
<div class="fusion-fullwidth fullwidth-box nonhundred-percent-fullwidth fusion-equal-height-columns fusion-no-small-visibility fusion-no-medium-visibility"  style='background-color: #6a1d1e;background-position: center center;background-repeat: no-repeat;padding-top:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:5px;margin-bottom: 5px;'><div class="fusion-builder-row fusion-row" style="margin-left:50px;margin-top:10px;"><div  class="fusion-layout-column fusion_builder_column fusion_builder_column_1_6  fusion-one-sixth fusion-column-first 1_6"  style='margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:20px;width:16.66%;width:calc(16.66% - ( ( 4% + 4% + 4% + 4% + 4% ) * 0.1666 ) );margin-right: 4%;'>
            <div class="fusion-column-wrapper" style="background-position:left top;background-repeat:no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;-o-background-size:cover;background-size:cover;"  data-bg-url="">
                <h2 style="color: #ffffff; text-align: center;">City:</h2>
<p style="text-align: center;"><select id="city" class="form-control" name="city"><option value="all-cities" <?php if($qs_city=="all-cities"){echo "selected";}?>>Select:</option><option value="all-cities" disabled>DeKalb County</option><option value="COLLINSVILLE" <?php if($qs_city=="COLLINSVILLE"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Collinsville</option><option value="CROSSVILLE" <?php if($qs_city=="CROSSVILLE"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Crossville</option><option value="DAWSON" <?php if($qs_city=="DAWSON"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dawson</option><option value="FLAT ROCK" <?php if($qs_city=="FLAT ROCK"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Flat Rock</option><option value="FORT PAYNE" <?php if($qs_city=="FORT PAYNE"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fort Payne</option><option value="FYFFE" <?php if($qs_city=="FYFFE"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fyffe</option><option value="GERALDINE" <?php if($qs_city=="GERALDINE"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Geraldine</option><option value="HAMMONDVILLE" <?php if($qs_city=="HAMMONDVILLE"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hammondville</option><option value="HENAGAR" <?php if($qs_city=="HENAGAR"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Henagar</option><option value="IDER" <?php if($qs_city=="IDER"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ider</option><option value="MENTONE" <?php if($qs_city=="MENTONE"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mentone</option><option value="PISGAH" <?php if($qs_city=="PISGAH"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Pisgah</option><option value="POWELL" <?php if($qs_city=="POWELL"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Powell</option><option value="RAINSVILLE" <?php if($qs_city=="RAINSVILLE"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Rainsville</option><option value="SECTION" <?php if($qs_city=="SECTION"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Section</option><option value="VALLEY HEAD" <?php if($qs_city=="VALLEY HEAD"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Valley Head</option><option value="all-cities" disabled>Cherokee County</option><option value="CEDAR BLUFF" <?php if($qs_city=="CEDAR BLUFF"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cedar Bluff</option><option value="CEDARTOWN" <?php if($qs_city=="CEDARTOWN"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cedartown</option><option value="CENTRE" <?php if($qs_city=="CENTRE"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Centre</option><option value="CHEROKEE" <?php if($qs_city=="CHEROKEE"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cherokee</option><option value="LEESBURG" <?php if($qs_city=="LEESBURG"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Leesburg</option><option value="PAINT ROCK" <?php if($qs_city=="PAINT ROCK"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Paint Rock</option><option value="SAND ROCK" <?php if($qs_city=="SAND ROCK"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sand Rock</option><option value="all-cities" disabled>Jackson County</option><option value="BRIDGEPORT" <?php if($qs_city=="BRIDGEPORT"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bridgeport</option><option value="DUTTON" <?php if($qs_city=="DUTTON"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dutton</option><option value="GURLEY" <?php if($qs_city=="GURLEY"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Gurley</option><option value="HOKES BLUFF" <?php if($qs_city=="HOKES BLUFF"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hokes Bluff</option><option value="HOLLYWOOD" <?php if($qs_city=="HOLLYWOOD"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hollywood</option><option value="HYTOP" <?php if($qs_city=="HYTOP"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hytop</option><option value="SCOTTSBORO" <?php if($qs_city=="SCOTTSBORO"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Scottsboro</option><option value="STEVENSON" <?php if($qs_city=="STEVENSON"){echo "selected";}?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stevenson</option></select></p><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div>

            </div>
        </div><div  class="fusion-layout-column fusion_builder_column fusion_builder_column_1_6  fusion-one-sixth 1_6"  style='margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:20px;width:16.66%;width:calc(16.66% - ( ( 4% + 4% + 4% + 4% + 4% ) * 0.1666 ) );margin-right: 4%;'>
            <div class="fusion-column-wrapper" style="background-position:left top;background-repeat:no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;-o-background-size:cover;background-size:cover;"  data-bg-url="">
                <h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Min. Price: </span></h2>
<p style="text-align: center;"><select id="price-min" class="form-control" name="price-min"><option value="0" <?php if($qs_price_min=="0"){echo "selected";}?>>No Minimum</option><option value="50000" <?php if($qs_price_min=="50000"){echo "selected";}?>>50,000</option><option value="100000" <?php if($qs_price_min=="100000"){echo "selected";}?>>100,000</option><option value="150000" <?php if($qs_price_min=="150000"){echo "selected";}?>>150,000</option><option value="200000" <?php if($qs_price_min=="200000"){echo "selected";}?>>200,000</option><option value="250000" <?php if($qs_price_min=="250000"){echo "selected";}?>>250,000</option><option value="300000" <?php if($qs_price_min=="300000"){echo "selected";}?>>300,000</option><option value="350000" <?php if($qs_price_min=="350000"){echo "selected";}?>>350,000</option><option value="400000" <?php if($qs_price_min=="400000"){echo "selected";}?>>400,000</option><option value="450000" <?php if($qs_price_min=="450000"){echo "selected";}?>>450,000</option><option value="500000" <?php if($qs_price_min=="500000"){echo "selected";}?>>500,000</option></select></p><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div>

            </div>
        </div><div  class="fusion-layout-column fusion_builder_column fusion_builder_column_1_6  fusion-one-sixth 1_6"  style='margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:20px;width:16.66%;width:calc(16.66% - ( ( 4% + 4% + 4% + 4% + 4% ) * 0.1666 ) );margin-right: 4%;'>
            <div class="fusion-column-wrapper" style="background-position:left top;background-repeat:no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;-o-background-size:cover;background-size:cover;"  data-bg-url="">
                <h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Max. Price:</span></h2>
<p style="text-align: center;"><select id="price-max" class="form-control" name="price-max"><option value="999999999" <?php if($qs_price_max=="999999999"){echo "selected";}?>>No Maximum</option><option value="100000" <?php if($qs_price_max=="100000"){echo "selected";}?>>100,000</option><option value="150000" <?php if($qs_price_max=="150000"){echo "selected";}?>>150,000</option><option value="200000" <?php if($qs_price_max=="200000"){echo "selected";}?>>200,000</option><option value="250000" <?php if($qs_price_max=="250000"){echo "selected";}?>>250,000</option><option value="300000" <?php if($qs_price_max=="300000"){echo "selected";}?>>300,000</option><option value="350000" <?php if($qs_price_max=="350000"){echo "selected";}?>>350,000</option><option value="400000" <?php if($qs_price_max=="400000"){echo "selected";}?>>400,000</option><option value="450000" <?php if($qs_price_max=="450000"){echo "selected";}?>>450,000</option><option value="500000" <?php if($qs_price_max=="500000"){echo "selected";}?>>500,000</option><option value="999999999">No Maximum</option></select></p><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div>

            </div>
        </div><div  class="fusion-layout-column fusion_builder_column fusion_builder_column_1_6  fusion-one-sixth 1_6"  style='margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:20px;width:16.66%;width:calc(16.66% - ( ( 4% + 4% + 4% + 4% + 4% ) * 0.1666 ) );margin-right: 4%;'>
            <div class="fusion-column-wrapper" style="background-position:left top;background-repeat:no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;-o-background-size:cover;background-size:cover;"  data-bg-url="">
                <h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Beds:</span></h2>
<p style="text-align: center;"><select id="beds" class="form-control" name="beds"><option value="1" <?php if($qs_beds=="1"){echo "selected";}?>>1</option><option value="2" <?php if($qs_beds=="2"){echo "selected";}?>>2</option><option value="3" <?php if($qs_beds=="3"){echo "selected";}?>>3</option><option value="4" <?php if($qs_beds=="4"){echo "selected";}?>>4</option><option value="5" <?php if($qs_beds=="5"){echo "selected";}?>>5</option></select></p><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div>

            </div>
        </div><div  class="fusion-layout-column fusion_builder_column fusion_builder_column_1_6  fusion-one-sixth 1_6"  style='margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:20px;width:16.66%;width:calc(16.66% - ( ( 4% + 4% + 4% + 4% + 4% ) * 0.1666 ) );margin-right: 4%;'>
            <div class="fusion-column-wrapper" style="background-position:left top;background-repeat:no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;-o-background-size:cover;background-size:cover;"  data-bg-url="">
                <h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Baths:</span></h2>
<p style="text-align: center;"><select id="baths" class="form-control" name="baths"><option value="1" <?php if($qs_baths=="1"){echo "selected";}?>>1</option><option value="2" <?php if($qs_baths=="2"){echo "selected";}?>>2</option><option value="3" <?php if($qs_baths=="3"){echo "selected";}?>>3</option><option value="4" <?php if($qs_baths=="4"){echo "selected";}?>>4</option><option value="5" <?php if($qs_baths=="5"){echo "selected";}?>>5</option></select></p><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div>

            </div>
        </div><div  class="fusion-layout-column fusion_builder_column fusion_builder_column_1_6  fusion-one-sixth fusion-column-last 1_6"  style='margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:20px;width:16.66%;width:calc(16.66% - ( ( 4% + 4% + 4% + 4% + 4% ) * 0.1666 ) );'>
            <div class="fusion-column-wrapper" style="background-position:left top;background-repeat:no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;-o-background-size:cover;background-size:cover;"  data-bg-url="">
                <p style="text-align:center;"><button class="fusion-button button-flat button-round button-large button-default button-1" type="submit" value="SEARCH">SEARCH</button></p><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div>

            </div>
        </div></div></div></form>
```

‘Back to Search’ button/link:

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Back to Search</a>
```

I think this may be because the homepage search form is not displayed on the page that the results are being displayed on. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I can provide more information or code if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try like that:

```js
$('#form').on('submit',function(e){
  $.post('google.com'.$(this).serialize(),function(data){
    //#do what you want here,in your url after handle a data redirect to your page,with this inputs.
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input name="title"/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```